# Что значит оператор _ в Scala?

Tags: scala

Например:

```
var connection: Connection = _
```

Comment: Начал писать ответ, но устал через полчаса. `_` наверно самый перегруженный символ в языке, используется где только можно. Но это не оператор, в большинстве случаев это заглушка имени переменной или типа, когда интересует только наличие элемента, а не сам элемент. Вроде все варианты расписаны [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). Если интересует конкретный случай использования - дополните вопрос.

Comment: Прочитал вопрос не полностью. `var connection: Connection = _` значит установить для connection значение по умолчанию, для чисел это вариации 0, для большинства прочих объектов - `null`

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: extrn - Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Переведи вопрос на прусский.

Comment: @Qwertiy даешь stackoverflow на прусском!

Comment: @yolosora, ой)))